# The difference between clone and unique cloner

Tags: github

When visiting the `Git clones` graph on my GitHub project (`Insights` -> `Traffic`), I noticed the graph shows two other values next to the dates. That being `Clones` and `Unique cloners`.

The value of the `Unique cloners` amount is usually smaller than `Clones` amount.

I could not figure out the difference between these two values.

Comment: This has also been answered on https://stackoverflow.com/q/25856280/10878491

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

GitHub will show you a graph with the total amount of clones the project has, as well as the amount of different people that have cloned the project.

As you can see in the screenshot shown below, `4 Clones` is found in the bottom left corner. This number indicates the **total amount of times** the project has been cloned.
In the middle of the bottom however, is the **total amount of people** that have cloned the project. In this case `3 Unique cloners`.

[image: Git clones graph]

The amount of clones and/or amount of unique cloners can also be seen when hovering over a certain date and will be shown like the image below.

[image]